# Set weight to columns in Sphinx SQL

Tags: sql, search, sphinx

I have query to sphinx index like this:

```
SELECT author_id 
  FROM books 
 WHERE MATCH(%s)
```

and I want to set specific weight to columns. For example column `book_title` is much more important than `book_description` and it is more important than `book_content`.

For example I would set:

- `book_title` weight: 10
- `book_description` weight: 5
- `book_content` weight: 1

How can I do it in sql query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see [in the manual](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxql-select) that you can pass `field_weights` on a per-query basis with the `OPTION` keyword. In your case you might want to use

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE MATCH(%s)
OPTION field_weights=(book_content=1, book_description=5, book_title=10)
```